# MongoDB dynamic subfield name

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document like:

```
{
  idx: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  v: "a"
}
```

In an aggregation query, I'd like to add a field `x` to the doc by taking the value of `v` and using it to find the corresponding value in `idx`. The resulting doc would look like:

```
{
  idx: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  v: "a",
  x: 1
}
```

I've tried things like `$addFields: {x: "$idx.$a"}` and `$addFields: {x: "$idx[$a]"}` but these are not working. I've scanned the list of pipeline operators but I don't see any that would help. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way but you can take advantage of [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator to get `idx` as an array of keys and values and then use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get matching element.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $addFields: {
                x: {
                    $let: {
                        vars: {
                            match: {
                                $arrayElemAt: [
                                    { $filter: { input: { $objectToArray: "$idx" }, cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.k", "$v" ] } } },
                                    0
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        in: "$$match.v"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YFBy6RwQt-u)

Comment: Thanks @mickl. It's a clever solution. However, the reason I'm trying to build the index and then access it is to avoid mongo having to search ($filter) to find all the values. That winds up being an O(n2) algo.
If no one provides a solution soon I'll accept your answer, mainly as a confirmation that "There's no easy way..."